# Trying to get auto Update to work with electron

Tags: electron, auto-update

I keep trying different tutorials, but they all seem to be scattered and out dated. 
Everyone that I am trying I am running into many errors or deprecated code.
Are there any newer tutorials or modules I can use to simplify this process?
Currently I am using electron-simple-updater, but with this I keep getting the error in the .app file that it can't find the require module. It finds it when i just run npm run electron though.
Also when I distribute the update, should it be in the .app file or the built -dist folder?